# Generic type as method parameter

Tags: java, generics, methods, parameters

I have an assignment that I'm having a little trouble with. The following method headers are required, and I can not change them. I have to provide an implementation of the following method:

```
contains2(T anEntry)
{
//my code here
}
```

that calls a private recursive method:

```
private boolean contains(T anEntry, Node startNode)
{
//my code here
}
```

My problem is, how to I get the input of type T from method contains2, and make it so method contains takes that same type T parameter? This is what I've tried.

```
private boolean contains2(T anEntry)
{
boolean found = false;
T entry = T anEntry;

Node startingNode = firstNode;

if (contains(entry, startingNode) = true)
found = true;

return found;

}//end method contains2

private boolean contains(T anEntry, Node startNode)
{
boolean found = false;
return found;
}//end method contains
```

I get the following error "required: variable, found: value" for the "entry" parameter for this line of code:

```
if (contains(entry, startingNode) = true)
```

Please ignore that my code isn't complete for the assignment, right now I just need that line of code to accept type T as input.

Comment: `T` is a type parameter to the class declaration, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @JimGarrison here is the class declaration.

    public class LList2<T> implements ListInterface<T>

Keep in mind, I can't change the method headers provided in this assignment, I can only add the code that goes inside the methods. How do I get the input parameters from method contains2, to go into the parameters for the method contains?

Comment: What is the definition of the Node class? Please show it

Comment: @Bohemian I purposely omitted that portion of the code as it's not relevant to the question. My question is how to take one methods type T variable (T anEntry), and use it as an argument in a completely different method that also requires (T anEntry).

Comment: It's very relevant. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
T entry = T anEntry;
```

This is invalid syntax. Setting aside for the moment the uselessness of declaring an extra reference to the input parameter and comparing a boolean value to `true`, you should simply omit the second `T` from that line.

Here's your other problem:

```
if(contains(entry, startingNode) = true)
```

Here you are trying to assign the value `true` to an expression.  You want the `==` operator.  Or just don't compare a boolean to `true` as that doesn't change the result.

Comment: I originally tried it without the second T. I still get the same error. I need entry to be of type variable, but the compiler is seeing it as type value.